# How to take flexible number of text inputs in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I want to take flexible number of text inputs in shiny

For single input I am using

> textInput("symbol","Enter the stock symbol",value = "SPY")

How can I take multiple inputs in the same text input box in the way that user submits one and then enters the next input in the same box?

I want to fetch data for all the symbols entered by the user.

Comment: You can let the user type more than one input and use some delimiter like comma and split the sentences?

Comment: symSplit<-strsplit(symbols, " ")                     I am currently using the same methodology, But I want the text box to refresh every time user enters the submit button

Comment: how are you checking if the user inputs a valid stick symbol? if you fetch them first, you could use `selectInput` with `selectize` for multiple input values and you are limiting what they can put in to valid entries

Comment: Thanks @KevinArseneau, I will look into this,

Comment: to refresh the input you can use `observeEvent({input$idOfSubmitButton},{updateTextInput(session = session,inputId = "symbol",value = "SPY")})`